# mysql advanced order by query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this in MySQL:

```
+-----+------+
| id  | type |
+-----+------+
| 149 |    8 |
| 150 |    7 |
| 151 |    8 |
| 152 |    7 |
| 153 |    5 |
| 154 |    6 |
| 155 |    3 |
| 156 |    2 |
| 157 |    4 |
| 158 |    2 |
| 159 |    1 |
| 160 |    0 |
+-----+------+
```

I would like to sort this table and receive results like this:

```
+-----+------+
| id  | type |
+-----+------+
| 151 |    8 |
| 152 |    7 |
| 154 |    6 |
| 153 |    5 |
| 157 |    4 |
| 155 |    3 |
| 158 |    2 |
| 159 |    1 |
| 160 |    0 |
| 149 |    8 |
| 150 |    7 |
| 156 |    2 |
+-----+------+
```

As further explanation, I want to sort type column like continues count down like this : `8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0,8,7,...`

Is it possible to sort table like that? or achieve that result by procedures or something else?

Comment: Mh maybe. But what's the practical reason for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 SELECT id, TYPE FROM (
   SELECT id, TYPE, 
   IF(@myvar = 0 OR @myvar = TYPE, @counter := @counter + 1, @counter := 1) sequence,  
   @myvar := TYPE FROM mytable 
   JOIN (SELECT @myvar := 0, @counter := 0 ) a
   ORDER BY TYPE DESC, id) b 
ORDER BY sequence, TYPE DESC,  id
```

This query will work for any level.

Put an outer query if necessary to fetch only relevant fields.

Checkout this [SqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/95290/1)

Comment: Thank you for your response, your code worked correctly, but as you can see I've edited the question and the unsorted table might have that data. do you have any idea for that situation?? sorry about editing..

Comment: @akbarian I have edited the answer also to incorporate your changes. I have put an outer query , Try this

Answer (score 0):

This will work only if frequency of type is **two**.

Write following code in procedure:

```
drop temporary table if exists tmp;
create temporary table tmp
select min(id) as min_id ,max(id) as max_id from  table_name group by type;

select * from table_name where id in( select max_id from tmp) order by type
union all
select * from table_name where id in(select min_id from tmp) order by type;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
select id,type from(
SELECT a.id, a.Type, count(*) as row_number FROM test a
JOIN test b ON a.type = b.type AND a.id >= b.id
GROUP BY a.Type, a.id) a
order by row_number
```