# Ordering values in SQL

Tags: mysql

[image: Lessons Table]

Is there any way that could sort the values on the table so I get one week (Monday-Sunday) and then next week, like it is described next

```
Monday .......
Tuesday ......
Wednesday ....
Thursday .....
Friday .......
Saturday .....
Sunday .......

Monday .......
Tuesday ......
Wednesday ....
Thursday .....
Friday .......
Saturday .....
Sunday .......

Monday .......
Tuesday ......
Wednesday ....
Thursday .....
Friday .......
Saturday .....
Sunday .......
```

If it is necessary I can modify the table structure.
I hope it makes sense.

Comment: There should atleast be a column in your table that specifies the order of the weeks to do so.

Comment: you need a date colum to do order by days

Comment: how is the data entered based on date or something?

Comment: Nope it just has lid as a primary key!

Comment: Is, there a way to do recursive group by and grab the nth value of Monday, Tuesday, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT lid, ordinal,DAY, class, teaher, STARTS, ENDS  FROM (
   SELECT lid, ordinal, DAY, class, teaher, STARTS, ENDS,
   IF(@myvar = 0 OR @myvar = ordinal, @counter := @counter + 1, @counter := 1) sequence,  
   @myvar := ordinal FROM mytable 
   JOIN (SELECT @myvar := 0, @counter := 0 ) a
   ORDER BY ordinal , lid) b 
ORDER BY sequence, ordinal ,  lid
```

Try this query. I have not tried it locally.

Similar question which I have answered is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324071/mysql-advanced-order-by-query/31324608#31324608)

EDIT :

To answer the questions raised in the comments below

1) How does it work?

Take the inner query and execute it separately. It assigns a sequence for all rows in a way that whenever the ordinal repeats, it increments the counter. When a new ordinal is found, it reset the counter to 1. Now with the help of outer query, it orders the result by the sequence and show the result. It would be best explained if you run these queries separately and analyse the result at each step

2) How to get it in a reverse order?

Change the final order by like 
`ORDER BY sequence desc, ordinal ,  lid`

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked! If it is not too much to ask for, I would like 1) if you could explain how this works, 2) how can I do the reverse (going in ascending order). I tried changing DESC for ASC but it is slightly off; it goes 0,2,3,4,5,6,0,1,2,3,4,5,6

Comment: @Gacci I have edited the answer with brief explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Create a table with Weekday and an orderingnumber. Then join this Table to order.
because the days of the week are stored as text, you can only map this to an ordering number.